# Is it possible to sync MS Outlook with specific Google Calendar?

Tags: google-calendar, outlook, synchronization

I wish to sync my work's Microsoft Outlook calendar **one-way** with Google Calendar so that I can view my events all together on my Google Account.

I wish to create a [new Calendar](http://support.google.com/calendar/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=37096) on Google Calendar called "work", which my Microsoft Outlook calendar will feed data to.

I've tried a few apps which allow me to sync the calendars, but it mainly seems to want to sync to my main Google Calendar, not a specific one.

Answer (score 1):

1. Sync your outlook calendar to [office online](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/outlook-help/publish-a-calendar-on-office-online-HA010080983.aspx?CTT=5&origin=HA010010490). See "grant access" section in the link.
2. Then just subscribe your google account to this calendar.

This method allow only one way synchronization (subscription) from Google Calendar to Outlook.

Comment: Could you add the key points from the link? We try to keep answers self-contained in case the link moves or is deleted at some point. Thanks, and welcome to WA SE.

Comment: From the link: The Publish to Office.com feature in Microsoft Outlook and the service it uses are being discontinued on April 5, 2014

Answer (score 0):

[Sync2](http://sync2.com) is your solution, you can select two or one way synchronization, and map/pair Outlook and Google Calendar of your choose

Answer (score 0):

Many third-party apps will do this. [SyncDroid.net](http://www.syncdroid.net/) has a great comparison of them and recommends [CompanionLink](http://www.companionlink.com) as both a Google and Android sync tool.

Answer (score -1):

[gSyncit](http://www.fieldstonsoftware.com/software/gsyncit3/index.shtml) is excellent tool that syncs Outlook and Google calendars. Currently there is only a desktop version so you cannot run it from Android. Still a great sync utility.

Comment: Please declare if you have an interest in this software.

Answer (score -2):

Folks,
This is a quick one for anyone who has an Android Phone (in my case a SAMSUNG NOTE) and wants to sync their OFFICE 2010 OUTLOOK calender to the phone and some other pointers in between. After MANY MANY hours messing around with this and investigating ALL the sync software and CRAZY ideas out there, here is the most SIMPLE solution.

Scenario.  I moved to outlook.mail on my phone because it was exactly the interface and layout I wanted. However what followed was crazy. Firstly I could sync my CONTACTS with my gmail account but then found to my amazement that you cannot then edit them on the phone, even confirmed by MS. They appear as Read Only contacts !   I was also not wanting to use the GMAIL calendar as I had OUTLOOK 2010 on my PC which WOULD already  sync perfectly to FOR MAIL to the outlook.com app on my phone.

However the CALENDAR wouldnt !  It would not sync with the Google Calendar interface on my phone and I didnt want to use GMAIL .

Hey Ho !   After hours of investigation, I thought I would try the SAMSUNg S PLANNER (calendar) which came with the phone.

Firstly I deleted the gmail and outlook.com accounts FROM THE S PLANNER settings,  to set everything up properly.

I then firstly added BACK my outlook.com mail account, and JUST synced the Calendar NOT ANYTHING ELSE as the mail synced back fine with the outlook.com app !

I then re added my GMAIL account and ONLY SYNCED the contacts !!!!!!!!

Summary !
1) This means I can now use my outlook.com app on my phone and it synces perfectly with Web Outlook AND Outlook 2010 on my PC.
2) I can also update my CALENDAR on WebOutlook AND Outlook 2010 and everything Synces perfectly to my phone using Samsung S Planner calendar. Just remember to hit send and receive and wait a few moments on Outlook2010 to check the calendar has updated on the phone.
3) And lastly I just use GMAIL now for my contacts as i can update them on the phone and they sync back to Gmail, UNTIL MS comes up with a proper solution in the future to resolve the issue of Read Only contacts on and an Android phone.

There we go everything working perfectly in a non perfect world !

Comment: And how is this a solution for Web Apps? How does this answer the original question?