# How do I subscribe to an Outlook.com calendar from my Google calendar?

Tags: calendar, google-calendar, outlook.com

All the help I find is for the opposite direction. I need my Outlook.com calendar to show up in my Google calendar, as the events I create in my windows phone don't sync to my main Google calendar.

I am not using the Outlook windows application.

I attempted to share the calendar from Outlook.com to my gmail address, but get an error:

> Sharing error
>  
>   Sorry, this invitation isn't valid anymore. The sender
>   may have taken away your permission, or you may have already declined
>   this invitation. If you'd like to see this calendar, ask its owner to
>   share it with you again.

If there is an alternative solution that accomplishes the result I want (my Outlook.com events showing up in Google calendar) that would be OK.

Comment: Can try either transferring - https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Transfer-calendars-between-Outlook-and-Google-Calendar-3a133146-a30f-45a2-8cf6-701e5962df59 or syncing - http://blogs.wsj.com/personal-technology/2014/07/15/syncing-microsoft-outlook-and-google-calendar-a-guide-to-the-nightmare/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Marco_Mi. replied on  May 6, 2013](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/ocalendar-oaddtask/how-to-embed-a-calendar-using-the-new-outlookcom/d2efa06b-37a3-434f-866c-a192641aa493)

1. Sign in to Calendar *(Outlook.com)*
2. On the toolbar, click Share
3. Select the calendar that you want to export/embed.
4. Click Get a link.
5. Under Show event details (click Create)
   Note: If step number 5 is already performed, just skip it and click Link to event details
6. Copy the link that you needed and paste it on the desired program/website.

Answer (score 0):

I think the easiest way now is to export the calendar from outlook.com and import the ical into google.

this thread also discusses a similar issue: [Is it possible to sync MS Outlook with specific Google Calendar?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/38964/is-it-possible-to-sync-ms-outlook-with-specific-google-calendar)

it also looks like the ability for google sync for non-business users was discontinued in 2012.
https://support.google.com/a/answer/2716936?hl=en